# If user is inactive then stop him to using the app. how can i achieve this

Tags: php, laravel, backend, rest

I'm using Laravel and JWT token for develop backend APIs for frontend developers.
I put status(active , inactive) column in database
If user status is inactive then restrict him to using the app.

part of login function which gives token on active user:

```
 if ($user->status == 'active') {
            return response()->json(
                ['data' => ['token' => $token, 'message' => 'Login successfully.', 'status' => true, 'user' => $user]],
                200               
            );
 }
 if ($user->status == 'inactive') {
             return response()->json(
                ['data' => ['token' => '', 'message' => 'User is inactive.', 'status' => false]],
                 200
            );
 }
```

my middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        try {
            $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException) {
                return response()->json(['data' => ['message' => 'Token is Invalid.', 'status' => false]],
                    200);
            } else if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException) {
                return response()->json(['data' => ['message' => 'Token is Expired.', 'status' => false]], 200);
            } else {
                return response()->json(['data' => ['message' => 'Authorization Token not found.', 'status' => false]], 200);
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: At the config of jwt you have a setting to set how many minutes a token should be valid. Set it as you want it and thats all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write another Middleware to check that user is active.
Put it after `auth` middleware and return `403` when `!$user->is_active`.

Answer (score 0):

For check the user is Active or inactive, It's better to check it in another middleware but if you want to check user active or inactive in this middleware.  The simplest way to get it:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        try {
            $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
            if ($user->status == 'inactive') {
                 return response()->json(['data' => ['token' => '', 'message' => 'User is inactive.', 'status' => false]], 403);
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException) {
                return response()->json(['data' => ['message' => 'Token is Invalid.', 'status' => false]],
                    200);
            } else if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException) {
                return response()->json(['data' => ['message' => 'Token is Expired.', 'status' => false]], 200);
            } else {
                return response()->json(['data' => ['message' => 'Authorization Token not found.', 'status' => false]], 200);
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```